# How can i export my tblrecords into csv file?

Tags: android

how can I export my tblrecords into csv file using button? Help guys :(

```
package com.example.rodgie.atry;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by rodgie on 1/1/2009.
 */
/**
 * This is all my database
 */
/**
 * I want to export all records into tblrecords in csv file, using button
 */

public class MyDbHelpers {

    //Database ng records
    public static final String tblrecord = "record";
    public static final String id = "_id";
    public static final String name = "name";
    public static final String middlename= "middle";
    public static final String lastname="lastname";
    public static final String date ="date";
    public static final String time="time";

    //table para sa user
    public static final String tableuser = "users";
    public static final String uid = "uid";
    public static final String username = "username";
    public static final String password = "password";

    public MyDbHelpers.DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private final Context ctx;
    private static final String TAG = "MyDbHelper";

    static final String DB_NAME = "rodgie.db";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

/**
 * i want my tblrecords export into csv file using button
 */

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + tblrecord + "(" + id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + name + " String(200), " + middlename + " String(100), " + lastname + " String(100), "+date + " String(100), "+time+" String(100));";

// my table in accounts
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE2 = "create table " + tableuser + "(" + uid + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + username + " String(100), " + password + " String(100));";

    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "     + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tblrecord);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public MyDbHelpers(Context context)
    {
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    //for add visitors
    public long insertData(String una, String pangalawa, String pangatlo, String araw, String oras)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(name, una);
        initialValues.put(middlename, pangalawa);
        initialValues.put(lastname, pangatlo);
        initialValues.put(date, araw);
        initialValues.put(time, oras);
        return mDb.insert(tblrecord, null, initialValues);

    }

    //para sa log in
    public long insertUser(String user, String pass)
    {
        ContentValues vil = new ContentValues();
        vil.put(username, user);
        vil.put(password, pass);
        return mDb.insert(tableuser, null, vil);
    }

    public MyDbHelpers open() throws SQLException
    {
        mDbHelper = new MyDbHelpers.DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        if (mDbHelper != null)
        {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public boolean deleteAllRecord()
    {
        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(tblrecord, null , null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchRecordByName(String inputText) throws SQLException
    {
        Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)
        {
            mCursor = mDb.query(tblrecord, new String[] {id, name, middlename, lastname, date, time},      null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            mCursor = mDb.query(true, tblrecord, new String[] {id, name, middlename, lastname, date, time},      name + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,     null, null, null, null);
        }
        if (mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    public Cursor fetchAllRecord() 
    {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(tblrecord, new String[] {id, name, middlename, lastname, date, time},     null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    public void insertSomeRecord()
    {
    }

    public int selectRecord()
    {
        String count = "SELECT * FROM " + tblrecord;
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(count, null);
        int i = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return i;
    }

    public int getUsers()
    {
        String count = "SELECT * FROM " + tableuser;
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(count, null);
        int i = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return i;
    }

    public void deleteUsers()
    {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        mDb.delete(tableuser, uid + "!= 0", null);
    }

    public void setUsername(String a, String b)
    {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(username, a);
        mDb.update(tableuser, content, username + " = '" + b + "'", null);
    }

    //bagong username ko to
    public boolean getUsername(String as)
    {
        String arg = "select " + username + " from " + tableuser + " where " + username + " = '" + as  + "';";
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(arg, null);
        int eger = c.getCount();
        c.close();
        if(eger > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //bagong password
    public void setPassword(String newa, String old)
    {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(password, newa);
        mDb.update(tableuser, content, password + " = '" + old + "'", null);
    }
    //pagkuha ng password
    public boolean getPassword(String old)
    {
        String arg = "select " + password + " from " + tableuser + " where " + password + " = '" + old  + "';";
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(arg, null);
        int eger = c.getCount();
        c.close();
        if(eger > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //signin lang muna to
    public boolean logingIn(String bag1, String bag2)
    {
        String arg = "select " + username + ", " + password + " from " + tableuser + " where " + username + " = '" + bag1 + "' and " + password + " = '" + bag2 + "';";
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(arg, null);
        int eger = c.getCount();
        c.close();


        if(eger > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    //para sa update ng user
    public void updateusers(String oldName, String newName, String oldPass, String newPass)
    {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(username, newName);
        args.put(password, newPass);
        mDb.update(tableuser, args, username + " = '" + oldName + "' and " + password + " = '" + oldPass + "'" , null);

    }

    //delete ko to
    public void deleteARecord(int fg)
    {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        mDb.delete(tblrecord, id + " = " + fg, null);
    }

    //update ko to
    public void update(int a,  String uname, String urealStocks, String ucurrentStocks, String uauthor, String ugenre)
    {
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues f = new ContentValues();

        f.put(name, uname);
        f.put(middlename, urealStocks);
        f.put(lastname, ucurrentStocks);
        f.put(date, uauthor);
        f.put(time, ugenre);
        mDb.update(tblrecord, f, id + " = " + a, null);
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can try [this](https://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php)

Comment: But my data came from database. BTW thanks for your example :)

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to write to csv?
It would be better if you create DTOs to help you better manage the data and then you can pass a DTO to a method like in the example above and use it to write to a .csv file

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a quick "not ideal" example of how you may accomplish this

### Create a User class

```
public class User{
    //properties
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    //constructor
    public User(String name, String password){
        this.userName = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    //getters and setters
    public String getUserName(){return userName;};
    public String getPassword(){return password;};
    public void setUserName(String userName){this.userName = userName;}
    public void setPassword(String password){this.password = password;}
}
```

### Update your getUsers() method

```
public List<User> getUsers(){
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    String count = "SELECT * FROM " + tableuser;
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(count, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNex()){
        //assuming that userName is 1st index and password is 2nd
        users.add(new User(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
    }
    return users;
}
```

### Writing the list of users to a .csv

```
private void writeToCsv(List<User> users){
    String outputFile = "users.csv";

    // before we open the file check to see if it already exists
    boolean alreadyExists = new File(outputFile).exists();

    try {
        // use FileWriter constructor that specifies open for appending
        CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true), ',');

        if (!alreadyExists)
        {
            csvOutput.write("userName");
            csvOutput.write("password");
            csvOutput.endRecord();
        }
        // else assume that the file already has the correct header line

        // write out a users to the .csv file
        for(User user : users){
            csvOutput.write(user.getUserName());
            csvOutput.write(user.getPassword());
            csvOutput.endRecord();
        }
        csvOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Then call the  writeToCsv() method

```
writeToCsv(getUsers());
```

Not a very good example but I hope it helped.